# Why was this question about the sexuality of a historic figure closed?

Tags: discussion

The question [Did the first Mughal emperor of India, Babur, write love poems for men?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/37559/is-it-true-that-the-first-mughal-emperor-of-india-babur-was-gay) was closed by a moderator on the ground of *"unclear what you're asking"* which seems strange to me, the question is pretty streight forward and clear to me.

Do we really need to define Homosexual?

Comment: A lot of cultures, past and present, have had social attitudes to sexuality that don't boil down to simply labeling people as straight or gay, so asking if a historical figure is gay may well be anachronistic. Which is why people wanted you to clarify what you were asking: what precisely do you mean by "gay".  It could cover purely romantic or sexual attitudes, purely experiences, some degree of bisexuality, changes in sexuality over time etc.

Comment: @PhillS, the original question isn't mine. Also, see the answer I posted here.

Answer (score 4):

- Was Babur infatuated with a teenaged boy?

That is a question about what went on in Babur's head, and impossible to answer.

- Did Babur write about loving a teenaged boy?

That's hard to falsify, but sure that could be a question here.

- Did Babur have sex with men or boys?

That is not part of the claim that I can see.

- Was Babur a homosexual?

This is where it starts getting murky.

Is this referring to exclusive attraction to the same sex? That is a question of what is going on in his brain, and off-topic

Is this referring to having sex exclusively with the same sex? The claim denies this.

Is this referring to ever having had same-sex sexual relations? This isn't part of the claim.

- Was Babur gay?

Maybe "gay" means the same as homosexual, maybe not quite, but both of these terms - and gay in particular - are modern concepts. To me, this reads like "Was Moses a Democrat?" There is an anachronism here.

The sexual practices of Babur should be evaluated within the sexual mores of the time, and we shouldn't attempt to use our own modern (and disputed) categories to judge him.

In conclusion,  it was unclear which of these questions the OP meant to ask - and many of them are off-topic - so I closed the question as Unclear.

Comment: A follow-up issue which wasn't used as part of the decision, but meant I didn't try any heroic efforts to save the question: Who cares?

Comment: "Was Moses a Democrat" - there's either a "Famous Question" badge for me about to happen on Politics.SE, or a whole lotta downvotes...

Answer (score 2):

This answer comes as a response to the comment left on this question, as well as comments left of the original question.

I don't think that we need to define Homosexuality in questions. It's simply

> sexual attraction to people of one's own sex.

And in the case of males, like in this case, it means sexual attraction to males. I do realize that sexual norms and practices have been different in different times and places, but those are not distinctions that the question needs to make, those are distinctions and clarifications that the answer needs to make.

Proof can come in many ways from a well documented homosexual relationship that the person in question took part it, love letters to other men, documented contemporary rumours, modern scholarly theories to no proof at all.

If context is needed for the sources, then the **answer** should provide it, if it was the normal thing for that society to have homosexual relations, then it should appear, if the "love letters" would be interpreted as such by a modern reader, but were ordinary at that time, and wouldn't be considered sexual in nature, it should appear in the answer. If some form of transgender issue was involved, like the [Hijra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijra_(South_Asia)) or [Balkan sworn virgins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balkan_sworn_virgins), then it should obviously appear as well.

But, the basic question "Did someone had sexual relations with other men" doesn't need any special interpretation, except with the obvious caveat that we can't know what a person truly feels, we can only know their actions, so we are interested in what the person did/write/say, and not what they desired/though/felt.

Comment: All good, but the question asks about being gay or homosexual which is a different thing, and unanswerable beyond self-determination. It reads like "person x fell in love with someone of the same sex, was he gay?"